# emacs + comint-dynamic-complete-filename after '='

Tags: bash, emacs, completion

Editing a Bash script I want to assign a filename to a variable.

E.g. inputfile=foo.txt

With std. settings I can't complete the filename without first inserting a space after the '='.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `comint-dynamic-complete` has been obsolete since Emacs 24.1.  The replacement function is `completion-at-point`.

Now, if you starting looking at what `completion-at-point` actually does in a shell script buffer, you'll eventually end up in comint anyway.  In particular, the function `comint--match-partial-filename` looks promising for an explanation of the behavior you described.

If I read that correctly, the problem here is that "=" is considered a valid part of a filename, at least on POSIX-like systems (see variable `comint-file-name-chars`).  So, the completion mechanism is trying to complete the filename "inputfile=/..." which it can obviously not find.

If you never use a "=" in your filenames (or you use it so rarely that the working completion outweighs other downsides), you may want to consider doing something like `(setq comint-file-name-chars "[]~/A-Za-z0-9+@:_.$#%,{}-")` in the shell script mode hook (if you are on a POSIX system; on Windows it would look slightly different).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bash-completion` assuming your not on windows.  It just requires a slight modification to work in `sh-mode` since it uses a comint function to determine the current completion candidate.

I like this because, in addition to completing filenames there, it also will give you all the nice readline completion like command line switches, etc.  Here is an example setup using `company`, but you could remove the company stuff, since all you really need is to add the modified completion-at-point function.

```
;; required packages: company bash-completion
(eval-when-compile
  (require cl-lib))

;; locally redefine comint-line-beginning-position so bash-completion
;; can work in sh-mode
(defun sh-bash-completion ()
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'comint-line-beginning-position)
             #'(lambda ()
                 (save-excursion
                   (sh-beginning-of-command)
                   (point)))))
    (let ((syntax (syntax-ppss)))
      (and (not (or (nth 3 syntax)
                    (nth 4 syntax)))
           (bash-completion-dynamic-complete)))))

;; put this in your sh-mode hook
(defun sh-completion-setup ()
  ;; add capf function
  (add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions
            'sh-bash-completion nil 'local)
  (company-mode)
  (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
  ;; use company completion-at-point
  (delq 'company-capf company-backends)
  (cl-pushnew 'company-capf company-backends)
  (setq-local company-transformers
              '(company-sort-by-backend-importance)))

(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook 'sh-completion-setup)
```